# A little help needed! I need to know what I'm doing wrong

Tags: java

I'm a beginner in Java and I'm creating this program to output the largest word in a string. Here's my program;

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int largest=0; 

    String Banana= new String("It is my phone");
    System.out.println("Results are;");
    for (String retval: Banana.split(" "))
    {
        for(int i=0; i<retval.length(); i++)
        {
            if(i>largest);
            {
                largest=i;
                System.out.println(retval);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I debug my program, it gives me the output

```
It It is is my my Phone Phone Phone Phone Phone
```

Can somebody tell me what I need to fix? I don't want it to print "it" and "is" and "Phone" should just be printed once.

Comment: You are splitting the sentenace into words, and then for each word, you do the inner loop the same amount of times as the lenght of that word. For the first words, that is two times, and for phone, that is five times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep the largest word in a variable and print it outside the loop. You also need to remove the `;` from `if(i > largest)`

```
public static void main(String []args) {
    int largest = 0; 
    String largestWord = "";
    String banana = new String("It is my phone");
    System.out.println("Results are;");
    for (String retval: banana.split(" ")) {
        for(int i = 0 ; i < retval.length() ; i++) {
            if(i > largest) {
                largest = i;
                largestWord = retval;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(largestWord);
}
```

As a side note, variables should start with lower case `Banana` -> `banana`

Answer (score 2):

You do not need nested loop.

Just use first loop (iterating through all the words) and store the longest word found so far on each iteration.

For more advanced usage of Java try to stick Stream API:

```
    Optional<String> longestWord= Arrays.stream("It is my phone".split(" "))
            .max(Comparator.comparing(String::length));
```

Answer (score 0):

First issue, you have a semicolon terminating your `if` body `if(i>largest);{` which leaves the block next to that unattached. Next, you only need to store the index of the largest `String` in the array you get from splitting your `String`. Java variable names start with a lower case letter (`banana` not `Banana`). Next, I would use `\\s+` in the regular expression (to consume any consecutive white space on input). And, I would use formatted io for printing the results ***after*** I finish the loop. Like,

```
int largest = 0;
String banana = "It is my phone";
String[] words = banana.split("\\s+");
for (int i = 1; i < words.length; i++) {
    if (words[i].length() > words[largest].length()) {
        largest = i;
    }
}
System.out.printf("Results are %s.%n", words[largest]);
```

Which outputs

```
Results are phone.
```

Comment: Thank you so much!